# What is the alternative method in Harmony OS for ViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent() in Android OS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am writing a class in JAVA to port a library from Android to Harmony OS. In the Android code given below, `getParent()` returns a `ViewParent` interface of the corresponding view

`view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);`

Now, the alternative of `ViewParent` in Harmony OS is `ComponentParent`, but it doesn't have a similar matching method `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()`.

What is the alternative implementation of `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()` in Harmony OS?

Regards, Subham

Answer (score 0):

It seems dispatchTouchEvent, onInterceptTouchEvent - requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent() methods are not available in HarmonyOS for now. But  those can be applied to components using abstract interface.  Please try this example (with translation if needed).

https://developer.51cto.com/art/202108/677495.htm